# WSO2 IS 520/530 userInfo issue openid

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Able to get only,

> {"sub":"u003@tenant.com@carbon.super"}

Things done :

- Not able to choose dialect in claim configuration in Wso2-IS 530
- [WSO2 IS 5.1.0 as OAuth/OIDC IdP response with different claims on UserInfo endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787558/wso2-is-5-1-0-as-oauth-oidc-idp-response-with-different-claims-on-userinfo-endpo)
- Issue : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4463
- Tried mapping claims & oidc etc .. nothing seems working : [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182926/wso2-identity-server-oauth-userinfo-no-role)

Can some one help me out ?

Update: 
call is made to

> https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token?scope=openid
>   Environment is "milti-tenant", I am basically trying to getUserInfo who resides within a domain, not a user from admin.

For a valid token, even the claims are not being fetched under service calls..: [reference Oauth2 validation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/OAuth2+Token+Validation)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042390/5820670 can you try out this answer?

Comment: @farasath, the mapping is not happening in 520 & 530, only subject is returned.

Comment: Can you update the question with what you are  exactly trying to achieve?
For example what claims are you trying to get from the userinfo response etc.

Comment: @farasath : updated ..